# Separate Kanban board for each Feature in TFS 2015

Tags: tfs-2015, kanban

Is there a way to create a Kanban board for each feature in TFS 2015?

Answer (score 0):

There is a features called swimlanes on TFS 2015 Kanban board, 
you can configure it and customize it to show for individual features (Backlog items)

Check [TFS 2015 Swimlanes](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/kanban/expedite-work)

[TFS Kanban board Swim lane customization walk through](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2013/03/05/tfs-kanban-board-swim-lane-customization-walk-through/)